# Sidekiq - Intermittent nonstart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm dealing with a frustrating bug - sometimes sidekiq doesn't start processing jobs. It's annoyingly intermittent.

When it happens, `sidekiq.log` shows no change (and it is running). The queue size remains at 0. I'm guessing it's getting lost in Redis.

In case it matters, I've got three environments of the same app running on the same machine (different environments), which I just put in (but the problem preceded them). Only one Redis running on the default port.

I know about `redis-cli MONITOR` but it spews out stuff so fast, and there's so much, that it's hard for me to figure out what is going on.

```
1491479154.190069 [0 127.0.0.1:38763] "brpop" "queue:default" "2"
1491479154.289507 [0 127.0.0.1:38753] "brpop" "queue:default" "2"
1491479154.289544 [0 127.0.0.1:38752] "brpop" "queue:default" "2"
/// snip... many lines of these
1491479154.364985 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "multi"
1491479154.365090 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "incrby" "stat:processed" "0"
1491479154.365107 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "incrby" "stat:processed:2017-04-06" "0"
1491479154.365128 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "incrby" "stat:failed" "0"
1491479154.365133 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "incrby" "stat:failed:2017-04-06" "0"
1491479154.365139 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "del" "server.name:32533:6befea0f66c0:workers"
1491479154.365149 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "expire" "server.name:32533:6befea0f66c0:workers" "60"
1491479154.365160 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "exec"
1491479154.365896 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "multi"
1491479154.365962 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "sadd" "processes" "server.name:32533:6befea0f66c0"
1491479154.365977 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "exists" "server.name:32533:6befea0f66c0"
1491479154.365987 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "hmset" "server.name:32533:6befea0f66c0" "info" "{\"hostname\":\"server.name\",\"started_at\":1491373877.8700902,\"pid\":2217,\"tag\":\"demo\",\"concurrency\":25,\"queues\":[\"default\"],\"labels\":[],\"identity\":\"server.name:32533:6befea0f66c0\"}" "busy" "0" "beat" "1491479154.3655496" "quiet" "false"
1491479154.366035 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "expire" "server.name:32533:6befea0f66c0" "60"
1491479154.366046 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "rpop" "server.name:32533:6befea0f66c0-signals"
1491479154.366058 [0 127.0.0.1:38772] "exec"
1491479154.389484 [0 127.0.0.1:38751] "brpop" "queue:default" "2"
```

How would one debug Redis and Sidekiq to solve this issue? I wanted to pipe with `grep` but I can't do it in the `redis-cli` interactive shell...

Ideas?

Comment: Looks like a memory issue!! Not answering as it doesn't feel like an "answer" and more like a "lead". Would be keen to know if anyone else has seen Sidekiq/Redis fail in this way (silently) when there isn't enough memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two instances with different environments running. As soon as I removed staging, production worked just fine. I guess it wasn't set up correctly.